# SSL implementation for SocketChannel in java

Tags: java, ssl, nio, jsse, socketchannel

I am looking at classes of the package java.nio.channels but only finding plain socket implementations. I can use the SSLEngine to encrypt and decrypt traffic, but that would be quite a bit of handling. Anybody knows of a proper implementation/extension of SocketChannel that handles crypto internally?

Comment: I have one but it is a commercial product.

Comment: @EJP can you please share the product's site?

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't have one at the moment. If you contact me off-site I can give you details. I'm not going to post an email address here but have a look for me at the Contacts page of http://www.dadaelectronics.eu.

Comment: @EJP dadaelectronics.eu states it's a site for quad amplifiers and tuners. Is this the right site?

Comment: That's the one.

Comment: @EJP There are 4-5 contacts in there. Which one do I use?

Comment: The one for Australia.

Answer (score 1):

**The most simple implementation that I've see was [alkarn SSL Engine Example](https://github.com/alkarn/sslengine.example).** This is *probably* what you're looking for. This is an actual implementation of SSLEngine and only has 3 classes in total. You can just copy that and run.

I'll paste some of his doc page here for convenience:

**Server**:

```
NioSslServer server = new NioSslServer("TLSv1.2", "localhost", 9222);
server.start();
```

**Client**

```
NioSslClient client = new NioSslClient("TLSv1.2", "localhost", 9222);
client.connect();
```

You may wonder why there isn't something like this just built in. Well, I'm not super familiar with this specific area, but I know that the following is in the JSSE Reference Guide:

> Newcomers to the API may wonder "Why not just have an SSLSocketChannel which extends java.nio.channels.SocketChannel?" There
>   are two main reasons:
>
> - There were a lot of very difficult questions about what a
>     SSLSocketChannel should be, including its class hierarchy and how it
>     should interoperate with Selectors and other types of SocketChannels.
>     Each proposal brought up more questions than answers. It was noted
>     that any new API abstraction extended to work with SSL/TLS would
>     require the same significant analysis and could result in large and
>     complex APIs.
> - Any JSSE implementation of a new API would be free to
>     choose the "best" I/O & compute strategy, but hiding any of these
>     details is inappropriate for those applications needing full control.
>     Any specific implementation would be inappropriate for some
>     application segment.

See: [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLENG)

I believe that the goal here is to allow the developer full control of the implementation so as to not make the package unusable.

---

**Alternative to SSLEngine**

You can also use Jetty or something like it:

There used to be something called "[SslSelectChannelConnector](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/8.1.17.v20150415/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ssl/SslSelectChannelConnector.html)" which might work depending on what you have available in your environment.
However, "SslSelectChannelConnector" has since been deprecated (I think since version 9)?

The replacement is [org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.4.v20170414/org/eclipse/jetty/server/SslConnectionFactory.html)

You can see the full docs here: [Jetty Docs 9.4.7.v20170914](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.7.v20170914/index.html?overview-summary.html)

Here is an example of SslConnectionFactory being used: [Eclipse Github Example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyConnectors.java)

You may find this "Embedded Jetty" method interesting as well: [Embedded Jetty Example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/LikeJettyXml.java)

Comment: Thanks @njfife, I am interested in an implementation of an SSLSocketChannel that would extend the SocketChannel indeed. Took a look at your suggestions but none has Selector functionality. Too bad Oracle does not have it (however complex, it seems it would be a huge benefit of having just that).

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that you cannot internally implement SSLEngine on a NBIO socket without a Selector Thread because the SSLEngine may have to read/write data at times when your code is not reading or writing.  The performance would be abysmal if implemented this way.

Comment: Agreed with your reasoning, so the implementation may need to use a Selector Thread. But that wouldn't be a show stopper though, right? Pinging @EJP since he may have that implementation.

Answer (score -1):

A very good example of sslEngine can be found at below git repo :
https://github.com/jesperdj/sslclient/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jesperdj/sslclient/SSLSocketChannel.java

Comment: why is this answer down voted ? For me this link indeed helped me to implement the read operation for sslengine.